# .NET vNext, EF7 beta6 - Missing Method exception when calling UserMananger.FindByEmailAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm getting this when calling `UserMananger.FindByEmailAsync`

```
Exception thrown: 'System.MissingMethodException' in EntityFramework.Core.dll

Additional information: Method not found: 'Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionVisitors.TreeEvaluation.PartialEvaluationInfo Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ExpressionVisitors.TreeEvaluation.EvaluatableTreeFindingExpressionVisitor.Analyze(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)'.
```

Here is my `project.json` dependencies:

```
"EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta6-*",
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta6-*",
"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-beta6-*",
"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.DataProtection": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Owin": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core": "5.2.3",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.Framework.DependencyInjection.Ninject": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta6-*",
"Microsoft.Owin": "3.0.1",
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are missing [re-linq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Remotion.Linq/2.0.0-beta-002). But this should be installed as it is a depencency of "EntityFramework.Core".

Try removing "EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta6-*", as this package does not and [will not exist](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/NuGet-Package-Naming#downsides). It could be the source of conflicts? Just a guess.

**Update:**
You can verify which version relinq is installed with `dnu list` and look under "Package References". You should have "Remotion.Linq 2.0.0-alpha-004"
 listed

Comment: Good try. Was hoping this was it, sadly nothing changed.

Comment: updated. debugging this issues is tough since beta6 is highly unstable still.